# Is betting on board games/chess gambling

Tags: halacha, derabanan, games-toys, leniencies, gambling

If someone makes a bet on something like chess or a board game, (we’ll include some types of card games as well), does that count as gambling in Halacha?

Gambling (between Jews) is prohibited de-rabbanan, but does that only apply to chance-based gambling? Or are competition games included?

Sources appreciated

Comment: First don't you have to ask, when is playing and keeping the pieces for example in marbles, equivalent to betting?

Comment: Is there any reason it wouldn't count as gambling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is very likely forbidden, even more so for Sedaradim but even according to many Ashkenazi decisors.**

For background (adapted from R Moishe Dovid Lebovits [here](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol13Issue18.pdf))

> The Mishnah in Maseches [Sanhedrin 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.24b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists people who are disqualified
> from being a witness. One of them is a “*mesacheik b’kubiya*”, a dice
> player. The Gemara discusses as to why a dice player is disqualified
> from being a witness and brings two opinions.
>
> One says that a winner is considered stealing from the losing party.
> This is called *asmachta*, which means doing an action under the
> assumption that he will never have to pay (each gambler agrees to pay
> but never really thinks he will lose, so when he hands over the money
> to the winner it is done unwillingly. This action is considered
> stealing on a rabbinic level.
>
> The second says dice playing is not allowed because one does not
> contribute to society that way. Therefore, he is only disqualified if
> gambling is his only profession. If he has another profession, then he
> is only gambling to pass time, and does not care if he loses.

**The Shulchan Aruch holds that gambling of any sort is considered stealing. This is how the Sephardim conduct themselves. The Rema permits it but with many limitations: there should be no skill involved, the gambler must not feel secure that he will win and the result must be based on luck.**

**Since chess, board and card games are skill-based, they would be forbidden.**

In addition, R Moishe Dovid Lebovits brings many poskim who raise societal reasons to stay far away from gambling

- The Rivash says that gambling kills people. It is
  disgusting, abominable, repulsive, and it is addictive.
- The Biur Halachah says that someone who is concerned
  for his soul should distance himself from gambling.
- The Aruch Hashulchan says that whoever can stop from
  gambling will have great reward.
- R Moshe Feinstein said that it is a disgusting act
  and is like joining a gathering of scornful people

See detailed sources [here](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol13Issue18.pdf) as well as in this detailed [overview](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/the-torahs-view-of-gambling-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter).

And of course [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).